# Remove characters from a list of strings

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of strings which has got some characters in it.
[image]

On viewing it in HTML viewer I get the following

[image]

I tried `line.Replace()` to remove some special characters but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string

Comment: And maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459641/replacing-characters-in-c-sharp-ascii

Answer (score 2):

This code will remove any non-printable or non-ASCII characters using regex:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\u0021-\u007F]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: OMG!!! IT works. Thanks a billion trillion...CHEERS

Comment: @TzahMama duplicate question :P will remove my question.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate. The answer he linked won't remove `\0`, for instance, which you had in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it lke this :

```
var specialChars = new char[] {'-', '!', '*'}; // your all special chars
var newstr = string.Concat(line.ToCharArray().Where(c => !specialChars.Contains(c)));
```

Hope this helps.