# Upload file to replace invalid to valid file name in c#

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I use this `static function` in c# on uploading a file to replace invalid file names by using `RegEx` :

```
static string removeBadChar(string filename)
{
   // Replace invalid characters with "_" char.
   return Regex.Replace(filename, @"[^\w\.-]", "_");    
}
```

And the `File Name.csv` is replaced with `File_Name.csv`

But I have another problem, if the file name of CSV expects these keyboard letters : `é, è, à, ù, ì, ò` the web application faults.

How can I resolve this?.

Comment: Why is a space a bad character? Could you elaborate on where this requirement comes from? How do you know the complete list of invalid characters?

Comment: Your regex should match your special chars also

Comment: What about the typical DOS invalid characters like `:`, `*`, `?`, `\\`, `/`, `|`, `"`, `<` and `>`? Also, AFAIK WebDAV does not allow `&`.

Comment: you can use this to get filename illegal characters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
all other characters you have to add yourself with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]+` to match all uppercase and lowercase unicode letters.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Replacing characters in C# (ASCII)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459641/replacing-characters-in-c-sharp-ascii/13154805#13154805)

I hope to have been helpful in solving your problem.